# Intellij 12 and Local tomcat issue

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a very simple web application that works fine on Tomcat 7 when deployed manually. I have configured a configuration for this local setting and server. When I run the application using Intellij, the application does not work nor is it there. I accessed the manager application while Intellij was controlling Tomcat and it showed only the manager application.

Help please

Comment: do you have a stacktrace ? 
add some screenshots of your tomcat run/debug configuration, at least server and deployment tabs

Comment: IntelliJ creates a copy, just config it correctly within intellij